# how to sort the numbers 1, ... n lexicographically without converting the numbers to string?

Tags: algorithm, math

Assume I have input `n` how I can print this sequence without convert the number to string?

i.e:-

`n = 100`
Output :- `1 10 100 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 2 20 ...`

`n = 15` Output :- `1 10 11 12 13 14 15 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`

`n = 20` Output :- `1 10 11 12 13 15 15 16 17 18 19 2 20 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`

What is the main factor here?

My initial solution that will print the 1's followed by 0's or 2's followed by 0's

```
 int n = 100;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        int x = i;
        while (x <= n) {
            System.out.println(x);
            x *= 10;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Two, actually. 1) I don't see the pattern here, and the examples are certainly open to multiple interpretations -- please specify the function you're after exactly. 2) Have you tried anything yet? Any starting points? (If the question is about _finding_ the pattern -- that's off topic, I'm pretty sure.)

Comment: @phipsgabler You can imagine naming files.... My first thought is that converting the second num to float?

Comment: Please, can you provide some more examples? I couldn't figure out a pattern from just these 2.

Comment: It appears the ordering is sorted based on the string representation of the number, rather than the numeric value.

Comment: @andand Yeah, but interviewer told me that I don't need to convert it to string... that's what i'm trying to figure...

Comment: So the question seems to be: how to print the numbers 1, ... n lexicographically sorted without converting the numbers to strings?

Comment: @coproc Thank you, edited

Comment: https://oeis.org/search?q=1+10+100+11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+19+2+20&language=english&go=Search

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the solution:-

You can call it with initial `k = 1` 
for example `printnum(15, 1`

```
void printnums(int n, int k) {
    if (k > n) {
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (k <= n) {
            System.out.println(k);

            k *= 10;
            printnums(n, k);
            k /= 10;
            k++;
            if (k % 10 == 0) return;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if there are more optimized one?

Comment: nice solution. a few simplifications are possible, e.g. `k *= 10; printnums(n, k); k /= 10;` is equivalent to `printnums(n, 10*k);`. Parameter `k` can have the default value 1.

Comment: Yes, depth first search is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Here a condensed solution in Python based on the OP's own answer:

```
def genRangeLexiSorted(n, k=1):
  for i in range(k, min(k+10-k%10, n+1)):
    yield i
    for j in genRangeLexiSorted(n, 10*i):
      yield j

def printnums(n):
  print(*list(genRangeLexiSorted(n)))
```

Then the calls

```
printnums(1)
printnums(9)
printnums(11)
printnums(20)
printnums(100)
```

give the following outputs:

```
1
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 10 11 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 2 20 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 10 100 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 2 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 3 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 4 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 5 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 6 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 7 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 8 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 9 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99
```